# No submit on Spring 3 form when user presses enter or any other key

Tags: spring, form-submit

How to gain function mentioned above?

Google is not very helpful with this-

Comment: Why minus? I think the question is really simple and clear!

Comment: Let's see the code you have for the form. You're probably missing an action.

Comment: You're saying that your form is not being submitted on enter press *OR* you want it to NOT submit when you press enter? Please give us more information. I think I understood it wrong. And maybe that's why you got negativated.

Comment: See, I don't have a form code..This was purely a theoretical question this time!

Comment: I did not understand the question. Rephrase it. Include the title in the question body as well. There are no functions in java, to begin with.

Comment: A form. that uses Spring 3 framework, should not be submitted when user presses enter. I can't phrase it better.

Answer (score 0):

What about this example http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-form-submit-on-enter-keypress.html